# How do I create a draft in Gmail using IMAP using GO

Tags: go, smtp, imap

I would like to use GO to create a new message (**specifically a draft**) that is stored in my inbox with everything ready to hit send at a later date. With SMTP I think it won't work. With IMAP maybe I can. How do I go about this?

Comment: Start here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go

Comment: I'm trying not to use the google api, because in the future I will use this script to send e-mails other than gmail.

Comment: Use `APPEND` , stick it the Drafts folder.

Comment: Thx Max, it worked. Now i'm trying to attach a file, but i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
    "github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("Connecting to server...")

    // Connect to server
    c, err := client.DialTLS(os.Getenv("IMAP_SERVER"), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connected")

    // Don't forget to logout
    defer c.Logout()

    // Login
    if err := c.Login(os.Getenv("IMAP_USER"), os.Getenv("IMAP_PASSWORD")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Logged in")

    // Write the message to a buffer
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.WriteString("From: <...@gmail.com>\r\n")
    b.WriteString("To: <...@gmail.com>\r\n")
    b.WriteString("Subject: Append test\r\n")
    b.WriteString("\r\n")
    // Message body
    b.WriteString("Append test using Gmail IMAP and Draft folder")

    // Append it to Drafts
    if err := c.Append("[Gmail]/Drafts", nil, time.Now(), &b); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```